# Javascript Switch statement not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a situation where I am going to get a decimal and I need to store different objects based on the outcome and I want to use a Switch/case statement to do this however its not acting how I would expect.

Here is the code......

```
var spread = high - low;
var closeDiff = close - low;
var answer = closeDiff / spread;

switch(answer <= .3999) {
    case (answer <= .3999):
    singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
    singleEntry["supportDay"] = false;
    console.log("answer <= .39999");
    break;
    case (answer > .95):
    singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
    singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;
    singleEntry["peakClose"] = true;
    console.log("answer > .95");
    break;
    default:
    singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
    singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;
    console.log("answer default");
}
```

It always defaults to the first case, even if `answer` is not lower than `.3999`. I have 7500 calculations to do and it always console's the code below.

```
console.log("answer <= .39999");
```

So whats the deal?

Comment: You have completely misunderstood how the `switch` statement works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` is not appropriate for what you're doing.

```
if (answer <= .3999) {
    singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
    singleEntry["supportDay"] = false;
    console.log("answer <= .39999");    
}
else if (answer > .95) {
    singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
    singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;
    singleEntry["peakClose"] = true;
    console.log("answer > .95");    
}
else {
    singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
    singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;
    console.log("answer default");
}
```

A `switch` statement is useful for choosing between one of several possible discrete outcomes of an expression. In your case, you have a variable that may have a value in one or another range, so that's not the same situation at all.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation, I was wondering if I was using it incorrectly. I just used an if/else.

Answer (score 1):

you have to understand about switch statement first. try to study this
[JavaScript Switch Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

```
switch(expression) {
case n:
    code block
    break;
case n:
    code block
    break;
default:
    default code block
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You have misunderstood the use of switch statement. It is used to compare truthy values of expression to the case . However if you want to stick to this format, you can do this.

```
var spread = high - low;
var closeDiff = close - low;
var answer = closeDiff / spread;

switch(true){
    case (answer <= .3999):
        singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
        singleEntry["supportDay"] = false;
        console.log("answer <= .39999");
        break;
    case (answer > .95):
        singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
        singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;
        singleEntry["peakClose"] = true;
        console.log("answer > .95");
        break;
    default:
        singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
        singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;
        console.log("answer default");                                          
    }
```

This will match the `true` condition to the first case expression that evaluates to true.